# Printing to CSV file with automatic width

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Is there any way in Pandas to write a `DataFrame` to a `csv` file where the column widths are **automatically adjusted**? (i.e. akin to what Pandas does when printing a `DataFrame` to the screen)

At the moment if I do

```
df.to_csv(string_buf, sep = ' ', Index=False)
print(string_buf.getvalue())
```

I get:

```
 column1 column2 column3
0 4 james matching68 -100
1 44 george foo -500
2 14 jason trinitron -400
3 1 tom trinitron -400
4 1 lukas esp -100
```

By the way, It's also strange that it prints the `Index` even though I explicitly disabled it.

Comment: The `index` keyword should be `index` not `Index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of being called Captain Obvious™, why not just write the result of `to_string()` to a file?

```
with open('csv.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.to_string())
```

If you don't want to write the index you'll probably need to use `numpy`:

```
df = DataFrame(randn(10, 3), columns=list('abc'))
values = df.values
columns = df.columns.values

with open('csv.csv', 'w') as f:
    savetxt(f, columns[newaxis], fmt='%10s')
    savetxt(f, values, fmt='%10.4f')
```

`cat csv.csv`:

```
      a          b          c
-0.8023    -0.6464    -0.2102
-1.4442    -0.5965     1.7326
 1.5028     1.7246    -0.4788
-1.6442    -0.3962     0.1391
 1.2404     1.1226    -0.3639
-0.6567     1.3464     0.2167
 0.4928     0.2204    -0.8549
-1.0625    -0.6588    -1.0551
-0.9175    -0.5855    -0.4151
```